# Text Macros in XCode not working?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, macros

Noob xcoder here and for some reason i cannot get the text macros to expand within xcode. For example if i type ifelse and then hit ^. it doesnt automatically expand the macro?? Likewise if i type fo and then ^. it will complete it to either for,fori etc, and will also pop up those options if i hit escape however i cannot get it to expand the macros unless i am misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the shortcut for menu item Edit->Next Completion is indeed ^. If it is not, go to Xcode preferences, Key Bindings and edit it.

Comment: Hi Costique, yea i have checked the key binding to make sure they were right, also tried using the menu instead of key binding with no luck. Also tried remapping keys. 

The strange thing is that it is recognizing the keywords and as i mentioned will complete them if i hit ^. or Escape and then select it. However after i hit enter it just completes the keyword instead of expanding the entire macro???

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your code sense index from the Project Info panel.

[image]